# Issue with Daterangepicker

Tags: daterangepicker

I'm using the daterangepicker from https://sensortower.github.io/daterangepicker/docs#configuration

```
$(".daterangepicker-field").daterangepicker({
  startDate:moment(),
  endDate:moment(),
  timeZone:'Europe/Bucharest',
  forceUpdate: true,
  orientation:'left',
  ranges:{},
  periods: ['day','week','month','year'],
  expanded:true,
  firstDayOfWeek: 0, 
  minDate:'2019-01-01',
  callback: function(startDate, endDate, period){
    var title = startDate.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' – ' + endDate.format('MMM D, YYYY');
    $(this).val(title);
  }
    });
```

The problem is, if I set the firstDayOfWeek: 1 (Monday), the calendar will change the label from Sunday to Monday, but in fact the days in the calendar will remain the same - so the calendar is wrong.
[image]

Can you help me figure out what is causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it, in case someone else needs it. The issue was related to moment.js.
I used the documentation found here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/dow-doy/
with the following code:

```
    moment.updateLocale("en", { week: {
  dow: 1, // First day of week is Monday
}});
```